# Issue with WMI data

Tags: c++, qt, wmi, gpu, windows

I want to get Video memory from GPU. I use WMI - Win32_VideoController class, property AdapterRAM. It returns value in bytes, so I convert it to MB:

```
int gpuRAM_MB = (gpuAdapterRAM.uintVal) / (1024) / (1024);
```

When I tried convert value to GB it returns as 3 GB (In other softwares such as AIDA64 it returns 4 GB):

```
int gpuRAM_GB = (gpuAdapterRAM.uintVal) / (1024) / (1024) / (1024);
```

My app:
[image]

AIDA64:

[image]

The issue is how to convert it to GB? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use floating point division and `ceil()` function.

`int gpuRAM_MB = ceil((gpuAdapterRAM.uintVal) / (1024.0) / (1024.0));`

Comment: It should be in GB so gpuRAM_GB = ceil((gpuAdapterRAM.uintVal) / (1024.0) / (1024.0) / (1024.0));Thanks.

Comment: If i solved your problem, please mark my answer as solution.